# JAVA Initialize a HashMap while declaring it

Tags: java, hashmap

I am currently working with a prefilled Hashmap, but I cannot come up with an efficient way to declare a Hashmap instantly.
One way I can do it is:

```
static final LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> test = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>() {{

}}
```

But I was told that this way is not good because of runtime etc..
I need a way though, to fill the List instantly and not in a method, because the method where I need it is accessed multiple times.

Comment: You can use a static initializer for your class ( `static {  /* your code here */ }` ) or you can use *lazy instantiation*. Note that final doesn't say much for collections, you'd make an final *immutable* field instead.

Comment: AFAIK using a static block would be the best approach

Comment: What are you accessing multiple times? And there isn't a fill the List instantly method really.

Answer (score 4):

Use `java.util.Map#of()` from Java 9+

```
static final Map<String, Integer> map = Map.of(
    "key1", 42,
    "key2", 69
);
```

If you specifically want a `HashMap`, use just that as a wrapper: `new HashMap(Map.of(...))`

Comment: That's *usually* a good way to initialize maps, but unfortunately [Unmodifiable Maps](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable) are documented with this sentence: "The iteration order of mappings is unspecified and is subject to change.". That's no good, if OP wanted to use a `LinkedHashMap`, supposedly in order to maintain insertion order.

Comment: @JoachimSauer but op's description they say they're using a hashmap so it doesn't soundlike the "LinkedHashMap" part is relevant.

Comment: Hmm, it does explicitly use a `SortedMap` implementation though.

Answer (score 3):

You can always do something like this:

```
static LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> test;

static {
  test = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>()
  test.put("key", 1);
  //etc
}
```

If you need it to be final then initialize it inline and fill the data in static block;

Comment: I'd use a separate local map variable and then only assign `Collections.unmodifiableMap(tempVar)` at the end of the static block.

Comment: That depends if you need functionality of `LinkedHashMap` which was in the initial code. But in principle I agree.

Comment: Good point, although I very much dislike mutable class variables myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a method for loading the map

```
static final Map<String, Integer> TEST = loadTest();

private static Map<String, Integer> loadTest() {
    Map<String, Integer> ret = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    // populate the map.
    return ret;
}
```

Another way to load the data lazily

```
static final Map<String, Integer> TEST = new LinkedHashMap<>();

static Integer getTest(String key) {
    return TEST.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> valueForKey(k));
}

static int valueForKey(String key) {
    // load one value, only called once per key
}
```

Comment: I'd use a separate local map variable and then only assign `Collections.unmodifiableMap(tempVar)` at the end of the static block.

Comment: Uh, or the unmodifiable [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSortedMap-java.util.SortedMap-) version of it of course.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes ideally I wouldn't even expose the Map, rather a method like `getTest(key)`

Comment: Yeah, and if you want order you can return an iterator over the keys I suppose. I'd even try and refrain from using `static`, but maybe that's a bridge too far in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> and not in a method, because the method where I need it is accessed multiple times.

That is a misconception.

```
static final LinkedHashMap singleton = createMap();

//called once.
private static LinkedHashMap<K,V> createMap(){
    //create and return map.
}

public LinkedHashMap<K, V> getMap(){
    return new LinkedHashMap<>(singleton);
}
```

The creation code is called once, and the map is accessed multiple times.